# Why kubectl exec --username=root does not work?

Tags: kubernetes, root, kubectl

I deployed istio/bookinfo on kubernetes, and I want to install stress on the microservice container to inject fault. However, When I use

```
kubectl exec -it reviews-v1-f55d74d54-kpxr2 -c reviews --username=root -- /bin/bash
```

to log in the container, it show that the user is still default. and the command 'apt-get' got

```
default@reviews-v2-6f4995984d-4752v:/$ apt-get update
Reading package lists... Done
E: List directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (13: Permission denied)
```

I tried to use 'su root' but I don't know the answer.
I searched some answer say that I can use 'docker exec', it works but it is not convenient, so I want to know how to log in the container by use the command kubectl exec.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not supported.

Source code suggests it's a TODO feature: [kubernetes/kubectl/pkg/cmd/exec/exec.go](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/blob/a0af655b7abaf06983c99ad5a4dc8f02ae5eb3e5/pkg/cmd/exec/exec.go#L100)

The `--username` flag explained by kubectl:

```
➜  ~ kubectl options  | grep user    
  --user='': The name of the kubeconfig user to use
  --username='': Username for basic authentication to the API server
```

As you probably see, none of the user flags can change user/UID for exec.

All flags supported by exec command:

```
➜  ~ kubectl exec --help
[...]

Options:
  -c, --container='': Container name. If omitted, the first container in the pod will be chosen
  -f, --filename=[]: to use to exec into the resource
      --pod-running-timeout=1m0s: The length of time (like 5s, 2m, or 3h, higher than zero) to wait until at least one
pod is running
  -i, --stdin=false: Pass stdin to the container
  -t, --tty=false: Stdin is a TTY
```

Additionally, apt-get update is best to be run at build time, not at a run time.

It is a good practise to keep your containers immutable. For testing purpouses you should stick with docker exec because ther is no other known alternative.

Also, If you have a specific problem to solve, explain the problem, not the solution. [xyproblem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this is very helpful.

Comment: k9s supports exec'ing onto a pod as root